# Is there anything that i missed in signed number in C language?

Tags: c, scanf

This is my basic C test program.
After I built it, I just entered negative number like `-1`, `-2`, etc. in console.
But the result is "oh", not "another number".
I don't know why this happens, because negative numbers should make the 'if' statement true.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    long int num;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    if(num ==1 || num < 0){
        printf("another number\n");
    }else{
        printf("oh\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the warning settings for your compiler.  This problem should have been caught by your compiler.

Comment: Why is the value entered in `num` for the code above when entering `-1` is converted to `unsigned int` in the `scanf()` ? What is the rule for casting that happened during that ? or is it considered as an undefined behavior ?

Comment: You're missing the required `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: @Meninx: You've fabricated `unsigned int`, there is none involved here.

Comment: I just tried to show the value stored and i found that it was `UINT_MAX` so I just **guessed** @BenVoigt ! But Keith gave the answer about that and then my guess was wrong !

Comment: @Meninx: Well, the two's-complement representation of `-1` is all bits set, and so is `UINT_MAX`, but the key is that the sign bit was contained in the portion of the variable that hasn't been overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `%d` format string with scanf, the corresponding argument will be treated as `int*`.  But you have passed a `long int*`.  The value `scanf` stores will not be the same size as what your `if` statement reads.

Formally, you get undefined behavior.  In practice, on most platforms `scanf` will write only part of the variable, and the rest will be left with an arbitrary value, with the usual bad effects on future use.

Comment: On many platforms (most 32-bit systems these days), `int` and `long` are the same size, so the code is likely to "work". It's still undefined behavior because of the incompatible types.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, in such cases "the rest" is nothing at all.  In other cases there could be trap values, or alignment requirements, and cause the whole thing to crash spectacularly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `%ld` for `long` variables, `%d` for `int`s. Change your code to one of these:

```
int num;
scanf("%d", &num);
```

or

```
long int num;
scanf("%ld", &num);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/tmp$ gcc -Wall foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:4:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘scanf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
foo.c:4:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’ [enabled by default]
foo.c:4:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat]
foo.c:7:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
foo.c:7:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
foo.c:9:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
foo.c:11:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

fix the causes of those warnings and all the bugs will go away.